# List all merged branches except the current one?

Tags: git

I want to display a list of all branches with Git 2.5.5 that have been merged into the current one except the current one itself (it might also be interesting to list all branches merged into specified branch `X` except `X` but my use case at hand only requires this for the current branch).

`git branch --merged` lists all merged branches including the current one, i. e. it will always list at least one branch.  I can use `git branch --merged | sed -ne 's/^  //p;'` to process the output of `git branch --merged` to DWIM.

Is there an existing porcelain command that lists all merged branches except the current one?  Are there other ways to get this list?

Comment: You can also use `git branch merge | grep -v \*` to process the output.  A bit cleaner looking than the `sed` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `git branch --merged` to get the details of the branches merged into the current branch(including the current branch). You can ignore the current branch (checkedout branch) by using grep or egrep to ignore the current branch (below is the command). I have tried this and it displayed all the branches merged into the current branch (excluding the current branch)

```
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|<current branch>)"
```

Comment: I would add that if you want to delete them, just pipe the output to xargs: git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|<current branch>)" | xargs git branch -D