# Get branch name from the most recent merge commit

Tags: git, version-control, branch

Whenever a branch starting with *release/** (like *release/1.0.0* or *release/1.0.1*) gets merged into *master* I would like to run a bash script on *master* branch. The script requires the name of the branch which was most recently merged into master (like *release/1.0.1*)

I have been trying for a few hours now but am not able to figure out and at most have found that it is somewhere along the lines of

`git for-each-ref --count=1 --sort=-committerdate`

`git reflog show master`

`git show :/^Merge`

Can I get branch name (like *release/1.0.1*) from the most recent merge commit on *master* branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all merged branches except the current one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507320/list-all-merged-branches-except-the-current-one)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+merged+branch